# Bootstrap-Confirmation jQuery plugin with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use [Bootstrap-Confirmation](http://mistic100.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/) plugin with AngularJS, but I cannot seem to get the directive to work properly. I am using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ozyXwLzFYs) YouTube video to get going.

A similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915122) uses another plugin called popConfirm, but it is used in similar way. I tried to replicate the directive, but that did not work either.

I want to show a confirmation dialog when the button is clicked, and IF 'Yes' is clicked, only then go through would ng-click function.

Here is a [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lktr55pb/) of it working in JQuery.

And here is a [**Plnkr Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NjHGSkaZ05zpbG9Dx8pq?p=preview) of what I have so far.

**Script Order:**

1. JQuery.js
2. Angular.js
3. UI-Bootstrap.js
4. Bootstrap.css
5. Boostrap-Confirmation.js
6. app.js

**Main HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" pop-confirm ng-click="confirm()">Confirm</button>
```

**App Directive:**

```
app.directive('popConfirm', function(){
    var linker = function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.confirmation();
    };

    return {
        link: linker
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this inbuilt jquery library
Here
https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

```
function confirm() {
BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Confirmation Required',
    message: 'Are you sure? You are about to delete this file.',
    size: "SIZE_SMALL",
    type: "type-danger",

    buttons: [{
        label: 'Yes',
        cssClass: 'btn-primary btn-sm',
        action: function(dialogItself){
           //your ajax codes here if you have or do any requests here
            dialogItself.close();
        }
    }, {
        label: 'No',
        cssClass: 'btn-default btn-sm',
        action: function(dialogItself){
            dialogItself.close();
        }
    }]
});
}
```

Comment: I am wanting to use Bootstrap-Confirmation plugin since that seems more elegant. Is there any way to get that to work? The other SO question I mentioned is similar and there was a solution for that one. I don't like popConfirm since the popup/tooltip is bigger than I want, otherwise I would have tried that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nprL2pc3/

Check that out, it should solve yr problems. Sorry for replying late

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am trying to make it into a directive so I can use ti with AngularJS.